# Same term used for Noah's ark and Moses's basket

Tags: genesis, exodus, moses, noah

In Genesis 6:14

> Make thee **an ark** of gopher wood; rooms shalt thou make in the ark, and
> shalt pitch it within and without with pitch.

The term used for "an ark" is *[tebah](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H8392&t=KJV)*. This term is also used in Exodus 2:3

> And when she could not longer hide him, she took for him **an ark** of
> bulrushes, and daubed it with slime and with pitch, and put the child
> therein; and she laid it in the flags by the river's brink.

We're seeing the same term representing the

- vessel which Noah built
- basket vessel in which Moses was placed

Is there more to it than meets the eye by having this term used only in two particular cases (which are linked with deliverance and two relevant persons)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Hebrew word תֵּבָה (tebah) occurs 28 times in the OT and simply means (literally), chest, box, coffin, etc.  That is, a box-like container used to house and protect some contents that are (by definition) precious.  See BDB meaning in appendix below.

Interestingly, the noun is only ever used to describe just two objects:

- Noah's ark - the great ship, 26 places in Gen 6-9
- Moses' ark of reeds line with pitch in Ex 2:3, 5

Given the basic meaning, it is not surprising that that such a word is used for these objects.  What **is** surprising is that the word used for "**ark** of the covenant".  In the latter case, the word is אָרוֹן (aron) which means "sarcophagus" and is only used to describe a box containing inanimate things such as:

- 2 Kings 10:10 - chest for money
- Gen 50:26 - Joseph's sarcophagus
- Judges 20:27, the tables of stone with the 10 commandments, etc

Thus, I suppose it is appropriate that תֵּבָה (tebah) describes a box containing people, animals and Moses; while אָרוֹן (aron) describes a box containing dead things like money a dead bodies and the law.

**APPENDIX**

BDB meaning for תֵּבָה (tebah)

תֵּבָה noun feminine ark (properly chest, box (compare Late Hebrew תֵּבָה); probably Egyptian loan-word from T-b-t, chest, coffin (Brugsch, ErmanZMG xlvi (1892), 123); > Babylonian word JenZA iv (1889), 272 f. HalJAssyr., 1888 {Nov.-Dec.}, 517); — absolute ׳ת Genesis 7:1 +; construct תֵּבַת Genesis 6:14; Exodus 2:3; — vessel in which infant Moses was laid among reeds Exodus 2:3 (made of papyrus, גֹּמֶא), Exodus 2:5 (both E; ᵐ5 θῖβις, θήβη, compare LewyFremdw. 100); vessel which saved Noah and his family, with animals, during flood (ᵐ5 κιβωτός): Genesis 7:1,7,9,17,23; Genesis 8:6,9 (twice in verse); Genesis 8:10,13; Genesis 9:18 (all J), Genesis 6:14 (made of עֲצֵי נֹפֶר), Genesis 6:14; Genesis 6:15; Genesis 6:16; Genesis 6:16; Genesis 6:18; Genesis 6:19; Genesis 7:13,15,18; Genesis 8:1,4,16,19; Genesis 9:10 (all P).

Comment: Up-voted +1 for the valuable piece of information that the first mention of _aron_ in scripture is a reference to Joseph's coffin, proving that the ark of the covenant represents a coffer, and thus the law is hid from sight in death. I would up-vote this piece of information many times, if I could.